# JasperRunManager cannot access content in the same security constraint

Tags: java, security, web, servlets, jasper-reports

I have a legacy application that uses servlet + jrxml files to present reports to users; this reports must access some images through a servlet

The image servlet is mapped as /images/ and in the web.xml file is secured like this

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>images</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

The reports use a servlet to fetch some data and then uses the JasperRunManager to create a pdf file based on some jrxml file; the code is something like this

```
inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(jrxmlFileName);
connection = getDatabaseConnection();
parameters.put("IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION", false);
bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(inputStream, parameters, connection);
servletOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

The report servlet is mapped similar to the images servlet

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>report</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/report</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

But when i run the report servlet it fails to access the images in the /images servlet; i know that this is some security problem because if i disable the security constraint for the images servlet then the report runs fine

is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: additional info, the application runs in a wildfly 10 server and the main exception is like this

16:07:23,302 ERROR [stderr] (default task-120) net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Image read failed.
16:07:23,303 ERROR [stderr] (default task-120)  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRJdk14ImageReader.readImage(JRJdk14ImageReader.java:72)